# Comparing strings of text files

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, file-io, foreach

I have three text files: file1 file2 and file3 all of which contain emails. file1 is supposed to have all the emails in there, file2 has all emails that are A-M, and file 3 have emails from n-z (This is not important but I figure it would help give a little context.)

I am writing a console application program in c# that will look at these three files, and if there is an email that is not 1 that where it should be, then it will write to a masterfile that will say what needs to be added to what.

For example, lets say I have the email `john@example.com`. If it is found in file1 but not in file2, the output of the masterfile needs to be `"this email needs to be added to file2: john@example.com"`. Now if it was reversed, and the email was found in file2 but not in file1, then the output should be `"this email needs to be added to file1: john@example.com"`

As part of my code, the answer I am looking for needs to be in some sort of foreach loop and if statements, however I am a little lost in what I need to put in. If someone could please help me in figuring out what it is I have to use in my statements I would very much appreciate it. If someone has a question about any of this please feel free to ask!

```
//Making a list for file1
List<string> listFullPack = new List<string>();
string line;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file1");
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    listFile1.Add(line);
}
sr.Close();

//Making a list for file2
List<string> listDen1 = new List<string>();
string line1;

StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader("file2");
while ((line1 = sr1.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    listFile2.Add(line1);
}
sr1.Close();

//Making a list for file3
List<string> listDen2 = new List<string>();
string line2;

StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader("file3");
while ((line2 = sr2.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    listFile3.Add(line2);
}
sr2.Close();

//This will double check that emails are in
foreach (string element in listFullPack)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(element);
    Debug.WriteLine(element);

    if (element == "jimbob@example.com")
    {

        Debugger.Break();
    }
}

//this will compare the file1 list to the file2 list
var firstNotSecond = listFile1.Except(listFile2).ToList();
var secondNotFirst = listFile2.Except(listFile1).ToList();

//this will compare the file2 list to the file3 list
var firstNotThird = listFile1.Except(listFile3).ToList();
var thirdNotFirst = listFile3.Except(listFile1).ToList();

//this will compare the file2 list to the file3 list
var secondNotThird = listFile2.Except(listFile3).ToList();
var thirdNotSecond = listFile3.Except(listFile2).ToList();

foreach (string element in listFile1) // This is where I am lost
{
    if (!)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Are the email addresses in each file sorted?

Comment: As a note, example emails are typically something like `email@example.com` or `example@email.com` or `burn.burnitall@aol.com`

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I know, I just wanted to do something different. Its friday haha

Comment: Regardless, `ill27@hotmail.com` will see a significant and unexplainable uptake in incoming spam :-)

Comment: Fair enough, but `ill27` is... Gosh*darnit* @user1911540 you stole my response!

Comment: He he, comment-Grinched...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something simple like this:

```
    //Making a list for file1
    HashSet<string> listFile1 = new HashSet<string>();
    string line;
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file1");
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        listFile1.Add(line);
    }
    sr.Close();

    //Making a list for file2
    HashSet<string> listFile2 = new HashSet<string>();
    string line1;
    StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader("file2");
    while ((line1 = sr1.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        listFile2.Add(line1);
    }
    sr1.Close();

    //Making a list for file3
    HashSet<string> listFile3 = new HashSet<string>();
    string line2;
    StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader("file3");
    while ((line2 = sr2.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        listFile3.Add(line2);
    }
    sr2.Close();

    IEnumerable<string> allEmails = listFile1.Union(listFile2).Union(listFile3);

    // this will double check the emails
    foreach (string element in allEmails)
    {
        if (!listFile1.Contains(element))
            System.Console.WriteLine("file 1 is missing " + element);

        int firstCharAscii = element.Trim().ToLower()[0];
        if (firstCharAscii < 110)
        {
            // less than "n"
            if (!listFile2.Contains(element))
                System.Console.WriteLine("file 2 is missing " + element);
            if (listFile3.Contains(element))
                System.Console.WriteLine("file 3 erroneously contains " + element);
        }
        else
        {
            // "n" or greater
            if (!listFile3.Contains(element))
                System.Console.WriteLine("file 3 is missing " + element);
            if (listFile2.Contains(element))
                System.Console.WriteLine("file 2 erroneously contains " + element);
        }
    }
```

Keep in mind, that as the number of emails grows large, the `List<string>.Contains()` method becomes an inefficient way of determining presence or absence. You would be much better suited with `HashSet<string>` class. Also, if for whatever reason you were reading in Unicode strings, you would need a more robust method for checking the first character's value.

Comment: You're close to what I am asking for, but not quite there yet. When I run this, it giving me every email and then giving me a long list of stuff that I don't actually need. what I need is just the list of emails that are missing

Comment: I edited the code to remove the reference to `listFullPack` and replace it with `listFile1`. I also changed some of the other list names since it seems like you have too many list objects. See if it works now.

Comment: Its better, but still a couple things wrong. I am getting the entire output of file1. I only need the missing files. Also when I run it. I get a "Console has stopped working" message, but it won't tell me the problem with the console

Comment: I made a few minor changes. The code as now posted above works for me in the IDE with some dummy lists with test values (note that I did not actually perform the file loading logic). If it doesn't for you, something else is going on outside the scope posted.

Comment: Last edit. I changed the code to use HashSets as suggested. It now double-checks the union of all of them and will no longer report any email twice if there are duplicates.

Comment: That last edit did it! You are a genius thank you for all your hard work

Comment: I just have one more quick question you do not have to do any editing at all. I noticed you had ascii and a code, could you please explain that to me so that in the future if I have something similar to this kind of problem I know how to handle it

Comment: All data in the computer is ultimately represented at the basic level as 1's and 0's (binary). This means than even characters inside a text string are just a pattern of 1's and 0's. So are integers. ASCII is simply looking at an 8-bit character and interpreting it as an equivalent integer. For example, an uppercase `'A'` has the same 1's and 0's as the `int` value 65. So lowercase `'n'` is the same as `int` 110. Because the chars come in alphabetical order, this simple numerical inequality is able to save checking 13 different characters (half the alphabet either up or down).

Comment: Just remember that uppercase and lowercase characters do not have the same ASCII integer values, which is why I chose to make all the characters lowercase prior to performing the check.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> fullList = File.ReadAllLines("fullist.txt").ToList<string>();
List<string> firstList = File.ReadAllLines("list1.txt").ToList<string>();
List<string> secondList = File.ReadAllLines("list2.txt").ToList<string>();

firstList.ForEach(m => {if (!fullList.Contains(m)/*Or other logic*/) {fullList.Add(m+" from 1 Needs to be in master");}});
secondList.ForEach(m => {if (!fullList.Contains(m)/*Or other logic*/) {fullList.Add(m+ " from 2 Needs to be in master");}});
```

Comment: Doesn't use and looping and little if statements. The object of this exercise is to use looping

Comment: If I'm not mistaken 'foreach' is a loop and there is an 'if' in each loop... The other bit in the /*Or other logic*/ can include your check that m[0] is in the range you are looking for. The ReadAllLines method makes the code much more readable. Also, if you are using streams use a 'using' or 'try...finally' pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you.

```
        List<string> file1Parsed = new List<string>();
        List<string> file2Parsed = new List<string>();
        List<string> file3Parsed = new List<string>();

        using (StreamReader readerFile1 = new StreamReader(@"c:\file1.txt"))
        {
            while (!readerFile1.EndOfStream)
            {
                file1Parsed.Add(readerFile1.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        using (StreamReader readerFile2 = new StreamReader(@"c:\file2.txt"))
        {
            while (!readerFile2.EndOfStream)
            {
                file2Parsed.Add(readerFile2.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        using (StreamReader readerFile3 = new StreamReader(@"c:\file3.txt"))
        {
            while (!readerFile3.EndOfStream)
            {
                file3Parsed.Add(readerFile3.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        char[] firstSet = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M' };
        char[] secondSet = { 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };

        var file1InFile2 = file1Parsed.Where(y => y.ToUpper().IndexOfAny(firstSet) == 0).Select(x => x);
        var file1InFile3 = file1Parsed.Where(y => y.ToUpper().IndexOfAny(secondSet) == 0).Select(x => x);

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\notExists.txt"))
        {
            file1InFile2.Where(x => !file2Parsed.Contains(x.Trim())).ToList().ForEach(y => writer.WriteLine("This email needs to be added to file2: " + y));
            file1InFile3.Where(x => !file3Parsed.Contains(x.Trim())).ToList().ForEach(y => writer.WriteLine("This email needs to be added to file3: " + y));
            file2Parsed.Where(x => !file1InFile2.Contains(x.Trim())).ToList().ForEach(y => writer.WriteLine("This email needs to be added to file1: " + y));
            file3Parsed.Where(x => !file1InFile3.Contains(x.Trim())).ToList().ForEach(y => writer.WriteLine("This email needs to be added to file1: " + y));
        }
```

I modified it for less code